# How to convert an excel file into a calc file from the command line ?

Tags: command-line, libreoffice, conversion

I know you can use libreoffice as a command line tool and one parameter to convert formats is --convert-to, I do not know of other programs.

However, I do not know how to make it work, what do I have to type with libreoffice or another program to convert from  excel to calc or the other way round?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the default extension to indicate what you want to convert your file *to*:

`libreoffice --convert-to xlsx filename.ods`

to convert a Calc file to Excel (this will create `filename.xlsx`), or

`libreoffice --convert-to ods filename.xlsx`

the other way around.

If you want to convert a batch of files in one go, use a *:

`libreoffice --convert-to ods *.xlsx`

If this doesn't work, either enter the command with `sudo`, or fix  ownership of your `.config` directory (see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/465988/convert-multiple-document-files-inside-their-current-folders)):

```
sudo chown -R --reference="$HOME" ~/.config
```

Comment: I recommend not using `sudo`; then you have the problem of the created files being root-owned, and that will continue until you're using root for everything - almost entirely defeating the point of having separate accounts.