# How to convert Microsoft Office XML formated spreadsheet to .xls file

Tags: command-line, libreoffice, convert, xml, xls

I have an Microsoft Office XML that starts with:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
```

How to convert it to a proper .xls or .ods spreadsheet using command line?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a thing about Microsoft software, but `libreoffice` provides a `--convert-to` option that I expect to be up to the task:

```
$ libreoffice --convert-to ods filename.xml
```

Further reading:

- [How to convert an excel file into a calc file from the command line ?](https://askubuntu.com/q/908852/507051)

---

To convert `xml` to `xls`, I just found this java conversion tool: [xml2xls](http://www.fhsolution.com/products/ariba-tools/xml2xls)